# How can I create a nested/split column header using TornadoFx?

Tags: kotlin, tornadofx

I'm creating a tableview that has 4 main headers, and each header has a "costs" and "units" property. [image: headers example]

In plain JavaFx, you can add columns to columns and make this split:

```
TableColumn emailCol = new TableColumn("Email");
TableColumn firstEmailCol = new TableColumn("Primary");
TableColumn secondEmailCol = new TableColumn("Secondary");
emailCol.getColumns().addAll(firstEmailCol, secondEmailCol);
```

is it possible to do this in tornadoFX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create nested columns in TornadoFX using the `nestedColumn` builder:

```
nestedColumn("header1") {
    column("costs", Item::costsProperty)
    column("units", Item::unitsProperty)
}
```

In addition to creating the columns, this code also creates a `valueFactory` for each column :)

Another very important thing to note, is that you can do absolutely everything you can do in JavaFX within TornadoFX. TornadoFX never hides the underlying JavaFX APIs, so even if we didn't have a `nestedColumn` builder, you could have used your exact code above, just with Kotlin syntax, and it would just work.

If you ever hit a case where you don't know how to do something in TornadoFX, you can always use the traditional JavaFX approach to achieve the same :)